# Remove debería sacar el último nodo ingresado y devolver su valor

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabado en un ejercicio en donde tengo un método `remove()` que debería sacar el último nodo ingresado de una lista enlazada y devolver su valor. El primer código de la variable current devuelve null si la lista está vacía. Ahora lo que tengo que lograr solucionar es que debería sacar el último nodo ingresado y devolver su valor (teniendo en cuenta si tengo una lista de un solo NODO y de una lista vacía).

```js
  
// TEST
it('remove deberia sacar el ultimo nodo ingresado y devolver su valor', function() {
    linkedList.add('first');
    linkedList.add('second');
    expect(linkedList.remove()).toBe('second');
    expect(linkedList.remove()).toBe('first');
  });

// CODIGO

function LinkedList() {
  this.head = null;
}

function Node(value) {
  this.value = value;
  this.next = null;

}

// METODO REMOVE QUE ESTUVE PROBRANDO

LinkedList.prototype.remove = function() {
  let current = this.head
  if(current === null)
    return null
  if(current.next === null){
    return null
  }  
  
  let aux = this.head
  while(aux.next.next != null){
    aux = aux.next;
  }
  aux.next = null;
  return aux
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error en tu método:

```
LinkedList.prototype.remove = function() {
  let current = this.head
  if(current === null)
    return null
  if(current.next === null){ // Si queda un elemento, devolvemos null
    return null
  }  
   // ... resto del código
}
```

Podrías escribirlo así

```
if(current.next === null){ // Si queda un elemento
  this.head = null;
  return current.value;
}
```

```js
class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head == null;
    
  }
  
  add(value) {
    let newNode = { value, next: null };
    if (this.head == null) {
      this.head = newNode;
    } else {
      let current = this.head;
      while (current.next != null) {
        current = current.next
      }
      current.next = newNode;
    }
  }
  
  remove() {
    if (this.head == null) {
      return null;
    }
    let current = this.head;
    if(current.next === null){ // Si queda un elemento
      this.head = null;
      return current.value;
    } 
    
    while (current.next.next != null) {
      current= current.next;
    }
    
    
    let last = current.next;
    current.next = null;
    return last.value;
    
  }
}

let lista = new LinkedList();
lista.add("uno");
lista.add("dos");
lista.add("tres");

console.log(lista.remove());
console.log(lista.remove());
console.log(lista.remove());
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. El problema que tenia en mi metodo es que me faltaba retornar el value? osea lo que entiendo es que debe devolver null si la lista esta vacia, eso si lo entendi lo que no lograba hacer era remover el ultimo nodo y devolverlo